# Point-free partial application inside pipe?

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I can't wrap my head around what method I'd reach for to make the following code point free. The following works, but requires intermediate state variables that seem unnecessary.

```
import { pipe, curryN, __, prop } from 'Ramda'
import ns from 'ns' 

// For the sake of this, let's say `ns.foo` is just `console.log` 
// (it can take any number of args)

const bar = pipe(
  prop('foo'),
  curryN(3),
  (x) => x(__, 'b', __),
  Promise.promisify, // or something
)(ns)

bar('a', 'c')
// => 'a b c'
```

[Here's a contrived version on the Ramda repl](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20foo%20%3D%20%28a%2C%20b%2C%20c%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log%28a%2C%20b%2C%20c%29%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20bar%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20curryN%283%29%2C%0A%20%20%28x%29%20%3D%3E%20x%28__%2C%20%27b%27%2C%20__%29%2C%0A%29%28foo%29%0A%0Abar%28%27a%27%2C%20%27c%27%29).

Comment: I don't see any *state* variables in your code?

Comment: `x` in the anonymous function `(x) => x(__, 'b', __),` after the `curryN(3)` is what I'm looking to try to remove.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get `(x) => x(__, 'b', __)` into a point-free form would be to use a flipped instance of `R.apply`, partially applied with the list of arguments.

```
R.flip(R.apply)([R.__, 'b'])
```

However I feel this starts to lose readability when compared to the original anonymous function, so always keep that in mind when looking for a point-free solution.

Comment: I was looking toward `apply` but it didn't occur to me to `flip` it. I agree that it starts to obscure the intent and makes the reader hang on that line longer (probably). Thanks for the answer! I'm going to leave this question open for a little longer and see if some other FP ninja can swoop in show me the light.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm just confused, but this looks like a simple `curry` around `foo`:

```
const foo = curry(function(a, b, c) {
  console.log(a, b, c)
})

const bar = foo(__, 'b')
```

Comment: The above is a contrived example, in my actual case, there is more to the pipeline. I also am working with an existing function from another library and I'm aiming to make a nicer interface (so I have an existing `foo` that I can't override and am therefore looking to do something in the pipeline). I updated the snippet on here to reflect these constraints.